# creating Pandas DataFrame as a cross-product between family x city x member

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

sorry if this may seem like a simple question, but I am new to python.
I would like to create a DataFrame containing 10 values for family names, 10 values for city of birth and for each pair of family name-city of birth, 3 members of that family, which have the "name" a random string up to 8 characters.
How can i create such a DataFrame?
I don't really know how to use the same pair of family name-city of birth for more than one value for "member".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this, but here's a simple one that's easy to follow (with 5 values instead of the required 10 but you get the idea) :

```
import random
import string

import pandas as pd

cities = ["New York", "London", "Paris", "Beijing", "Casablanca"]
names = ["Smith", "Heston", "Dupont", "Torvalds", "Clooney"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "city": cities[i],
            "family_name": names[i],
            "first_name": "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(8)]),
        }
        for i in range(5)
        for _ in range(3)
    ]
)

print(df)
```

Comment: Probably because SO is not a code-writing service, and when extremely low-quality questions are answered, it leads to even more low-quality questions.

Comment: The objective he was aiming for was well defined and clear. That's more than I can for 90% of the questions here.

Comment: The question downvote reason (hover to see) says: this question does not show any research effort: it is unclear or not useful. It may be clear, but it does not show any research effort, and is not useful. Side note: sooo many questions here are low-quality. Note, I didn't DV your answer, but the question, yes.

Comment: Also relevant: [recent meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413397/9245853).

Comment: this is indeed a low quality "answer" because it is almost code only, no attempt to explain